# Shared preferences for storing ListView data

Tags: java, android

In android app I have list view where you can add new objects, each 'object' have 4-5 string values. 
I dont predict anyone could use more 3 or 4 of those objects in app.

As for now its made on database, SQLite, one object = one record, with 4-5 values (type TEXT), but its getting harder and harder to maintain, and I think its adding to app circuitous.

Could it be done by shared preferences ? Or its not good idea to store such data ?
How about keys and values, can i generete them on go ?

Comment: No, shared preferences cannot be used to store larger objects, its a bad thing to do so. [Developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Gson to put object in Shared Preferences. You can find it [here](https://github.com/google/gson) and how to add it to your project like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library). Don't forget to add dependency in gradle file 'build.gradle' `compile files ('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')`.

To put object in Shared Preferences use the following:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String serializedObj = gson.toJson(ObjectHere);
editor.putString("key", serializedObj);
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve the data later do the following

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String serializedObj = preferences.getString("key", "DEFAULT");
    ObjectType object = gson.fromJson(serializedObj, Object.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the data as a file and retrieve it when needed using the filename:

```
    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

It would be better if u perform this task in a background thread for instance an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using gson(https://github.com/google/gson). Simply add `compile files ('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')` on your gradle dependencies section.

Suppose you are using Arraylist of
 `class YOUR_CLASS`
for listview. ie

```
private ArrayList<YOUR_CLASS> arraylist = new ArrayList<YOUR_CLASS>();
```

Now after adding item objects to your `arraylist` you can save it in Shared preference using:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

Gson gson = new Gson();
String arraylist_in_string = gson.toJson(arraylist).toString(); //Converting it to String
editor.putString("YOUR_KEY", arraylist_in_string); //now saving the String
editor.commit();
```

Now when you need to use the `arraylist` you can take it from sharedPreferences using

```
     Gson gson = new Gson();
        String arraylist_in_string = preferences.getString("YOUR_KEY", null);
    if(arraylist_in_string != null) //if we have list saved
    { 
//creating a list of YOUR_CLASS from the string response
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YOUR_CLASS>>() {}.getType();
        List<YOUR_CLASS> list = new Gson().fromJson(arraylist_in_string, type);
//now adding the list to your arraylist
    if (list != null && list.size() > 0 )) {
    arraylist.clear();// before clearing check if its not null. 
                    arraylist.addAll(list);
    }else //ie list isn't saved yet
    {
    //You may want to save the arraylist into Shared preference using previous method 
    }
```